# Better way to edit existing comments

Tags: jquery

I am in the middle of adding some jQuery editing/deleting of existing comments, and I am making kind of a mess so I thought I'd ask for advice on a better way of doing it.

Here is a test page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=228

Here is test login: testing@problemio.com / testing

If you go to the comments tab and add a comment and then click on edit, the bottom text area for adding the comment does not disappear.  But it should since I do a hide() function on it.  Here is my code:

Form I am trying to hide:

```
     <p class="comment_bottom_text">
          <!-- Make a form for people to add comments -->
          <form id="add_comment" name="problem_comment_form" method="post">
               <p>
                  <textarea name="problem_comment" cols=70 rows=6 id="problem_comment"></textarea>
               </p>
               <p>
                  <input type="hidden" id="comment_problem_id" name="problem_id" value="<?php echo $problem_id; ?>" />

                  <span class="error"   id="add_message_error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
                  <span class="success" id="add_message_success" style="display:none"> Message Added Successfully!</span>

                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Message"></input>
               </p>
          </form>
     <p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.edit_comment').live('click' , function() 
{
    // Showing the wait image
    $("#loading").show();

    var problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");
    var problem_comment_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_comment_id");  
    var problem_comment_text = $(this).attr("data-problem_text");

    // problem_comment_text_'.$problem_comment_id.'
    var div_name = "problem_comment_text_" + problem_comment_id;
    //alert ("div name: " + div_name );
        //var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&problem_comment_id=' + problem_comment_id;

    // Now validate the input
        if( problem_id == '' || problem_comment_id == '' )
        {
       //$('#add_message_success').fadeIn(200).hide();
        //$('#add_message_error').fadeOut(200).show();          
        }
        else
        {   
            // Check if the person is logged in.
            // Now check if the person is logged in.
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/auth/check_login.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#loading").hide();

                    //Maybe just switch up how the forms look like here.
                    // 1) close that piece of HTML
                    // Get the name of that piece of HTML.
                    // problem_comment_'.$problem_comment_id.'
                    // Close div named:                         
                    $("#" + div_name).hide();  // Works

                    // 2) Make an HTML form and display it in that piece of HTML
                    var new_comment_form = "<form id='add_comment' method='post'><p><textarea name='problem_comment' cols=60 rows=6 id='problem_comment'>" + problem_comment_text + "</textarea></p><p><input type='hidden' id='problem_id' name='problem_id' value='" + problem_id + "'><input type='hidden' id='problem_comment_id' value='" + problem_comment_id + "'></p><p><input type='submit' class='button' value='Edit Message'></input></p></form>";

                    // Now replace the current form with the crap I made above.
                    $("#" + div_name).html( new_comment_form );  // Works
                    $("#" + div_name).show(  );  // Works

                    //alert("before hide");
                    // 3) Hide the other text area form.
                    $(".comment_bottom_text").hide(); // TODO - MAKE THIS WORK
                    //alert("after hide");
                    // 4) Give a cancel button to undo the whole thing I did here. 
                },
                error: function(json) // Error for checking if user is logged in.
                {
                    // Showing the wait image
                    $("#loading").hide();                    

                    $("#loginpopup").dialog();

                    return false;           
                }
        });
        }         

     return false;
});
```

Comment: Looks like a code review request, not a question.

Comment: @GolezTrol the question is how to make that div disappear which isn't disappearing with this code: $(".comment_bottom_text").hide(); // TODO - MAKE THIS WORK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the html element you tried to hide does not contains the form and the buttom you want to hide.
This is how the html looks like if you look in the code of your web:

```
<p class="comment_bottom_text" style="display: none; ">
               <!-- Make a form for people to add comments -->
                  </p>
```

And after this you have the form.
So this is not a jquery problem or error you are just hidden something you do not want to, please review the code that puts the form inside that

or change the selector

Comment: In fact the <CODE>style="display: none; "</CODE> part of the html I pasted above appears when you click the edit so the code works perfectly!!! Please be sure of make more specific questions and try to understand better your code so someonelse may help you

Comment: !sandino hmmm, you know that is not how I see the code.  I am pasting the form code that I have in my original question.

Comment: you see up there the <p> tags are properly closed and I am not sure where you see the disply:none; styling.  I don't have it.

Comment: I see it using chrome browser. I see the display:none after I click in the Edit link.

Comment: The code you updated (the p definition) is what is in your code or actually the code you see in a browser when you inspect it?. You are probabily in a tag mistmatch problem, review all your html tags are closed, use a tool to validate your markup (http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I entered your site and now is working, please close the question if now is working ok, so I do not waste my time. Glad you solve it :)...here is a temporary capture that show its working http://awesomescreenshot.com/099p14l4a :)